# Why does this simple pitch shift core cell in Reaktor not function the way it was intended to?

Tags: music, programming, reaktor

I have created a circuit that does the following:

1. Writes incoming audio data to an array, beginning at 0.
2. Reads incoming audio data from array, beginning at one greater than where it was written.

   Ideally, it's supposed to write for the length of the repeat, then start reading.
3. Every time a counter hits a predefined number (called "pitch"), the value called "delay" is incremented by +1.
4. This delay is the maximum value of the array address, thus every time it increases, it adds a delay of one.
5. In addition, the previous value is copied, each time the array location resets, preventing added high frequencies due to large changes from sample to sample.

Effectively, this should progressively increase a delay every specified number of samples, adding a copied sample, and thus decrease the pitch by an amount determined by the "pitch" value.

However, instead it presents the pitch with a crazy delay and crazy sound interference (although this varies, randomly, apparently, as sometimes it has not added a high frequency).

Essentially, this is what the in looks like:

```
1234321234321234321234321
```

This is what the out should look like with a pitch value of "2"

```
1223443221223443221223443221223443221
```

Thus, the pitch should be 2/3rds of the original without noticeable distortion.

Here's my program (it's mostly clocks and counters):

[image: Reaktor Patch]

Comment: Have you tried breaking this giant core cell into six smaller core cells, and debugging them individually?

Comment: Yes, although I didn't see a need to separate them visually, so I just kept them in the one cell. I used debug mode and all of the outputs of all of the clocks are working fine. The only thing that's not working is the top section, which has the array used for delay. (Everything above the first space a bit below where the "pitch" input is.)

Comment: You should try to make the smallest possible patch that has the problematic stuff in it. That allows you to eliminate everything else as possible sources of error. Your patch is so huge that I don't know where to start on it.

Comment: It's the top contiguous section. I tried to organize everything in the cell without extra cells, since that added having to click on it and going to a different window.

Comment: I get that, but debugging will be easier if you can narrow down the problem are and then actually isolate it from everything else. 90% of the time, when I do that, I find the problem myself. The other 10% of the time, it makes it possible for others to understand what I'm doing and help me to find the problem.

Comment: If you fed it with a simple triangle wave, what does the output look like

Comment: It would look like stairs. Here's what happens with a sine wave: http://i.imgur.com/b6WFR36.jpg . You can see that it's not adding any delay, just replacing a sample when there's supposed to be a delay, so the delay section is not working.